# Get indices of characters in string for interpolation

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

I have create a method that given a string will find all interpolation points relative to a certain pattern `some string {{point}}` this is working however its not very elegant and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a cleaner more minified way of doing this?

Here is my method:

```
_interoplationPoints: function(string){
    var startReg = /{{/gi,
        endReg = /}}/gi,
        indices = {start: [],end: []},
        match;
    while (match = startReg.exec(string)) indices.start.push(match.index);
    while (match = endReg.exec(string)) indices.end.push(match.index);
    return indices;
},
```

Given a string it will check for all start and end points `{{` & `}}` it will then return an object with the start and end points of each occurance of `{{}}`.

The reason for me doing this is I will later `substring()` these indexes with there relevant value.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not simply `String.replace`ing the placeholders in one go? The offsets will change once you start to `substr` in new values, so this is all quite messy it'd seem.

Comment: I can't replace as the string will keep changing, the original string `some string {{value}}` will be stored alongside the binding data which is referenced each time `value` is changed. The interpolation points are assigned on compile and reused with the original value to set `textNode.nodeValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much simpler, but:

```
_interoplationPoints: function(string){
    var reg = /{{[^}]*}}/gi,
        indices = {start: [],end: []},
        match;
    while (match = reg.exec(string)) {
        indices.start.push(match.index);
        indices.end.push(match.index + match[0].length - 2);
    }
    return indices;
},
```

This regular expression matches `{{` followed by an expression of any length that does not contain a closing brace `[^}]*` followed by `}}`.  the end index is computed by adding the length of the match (which would put it just beyond the second closing brace) then subtracting 2 since there are two closing braces.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was trying to achieve